# reduce bouncing UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

is it possible to somehow **reduce the bouncing height** at the top or the end of an UITableView?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without disabling it entirely, via the `UIScrollView` property `bounces`. It's pretty much an on-or-off thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check and set the `contentOffset` property in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{    
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -100)
    {
        CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.y = -100;
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt so. The elasticity of scroll views is an implementation detail and it doesn't appear that the `UIScrollView` class exposes properties that let you adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

As additional to [René Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12564311/3080851) answer follow the full code to reduce bounce top and bottom.

Swift Version:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    if (offset.y < bounceLimit) {
        offset.y = bounceLimit;
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }

    let offsetY = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height - offset.y
    if (offsetY < bounceLimit) {
        offset.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y - (bounceLimit + abs(offsetY));
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

Obj-C Version:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    if (offset.y <= -100)
    {
        offset.y = -100;
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }

    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height - offset.y

    if (offsetY < bounceLimit) {
        offset.y = offset.y - (bounceLimit + abs(offsetY));
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

Note: The height of the table (`contentSize.height`) should be at least the device screen height less the bounce limit.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot changing bounceing property of scrollview either you can disable or enable